# Create breadcrumbs navigation using HIERARCHYID?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, hierarchy, hierarchyid

I have `Product Categories` table in Microsoft SQL Server:

| CategoryID (IDENTITY) | Node (HIERARCHYID) | CategoryName (NVARCHAR(100) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0x | Products |
| 2 | 0x58 | Main Category 1 |
| 3 | 0x68 | Main Category 2 |
| 4 | 0x5AC0 | Subcategory 1A |
| 5 | 0x5B40 | Subcategory 1B |

I want to display breadcrumbs for each category, for example for Subcategory 1A:

```
Products > Main Category 1 > Subcategory 1A
```

Do I use recursive CTE as if there was a self join (`ParentID`) instead of `HIERARCHYID`, or does this work differently with `HIERARCHYID`? All materials I found on the internet regarding breadcrumbs assume that `ParentID` is used, not `HIERARCHYID`.

Can you please provide me an example?

Thank you.

Comment: Find all ancestors and order by Node ? There's no need for a recursive CTE

Comment: Ok, how do I display the ">" symbol between the levels?

Comment: That's the job of your web framework, not SQL. Breadcrumbs include links to parent nodes and styling. HTML doesn't respect whitespace so if you want to control the spacing between the crumbs you'll have to use styling

Comment: Besides, all web apps use components for breadcrumbs, not raw HTML. All such components, whether custom or part of a library, which work with lists of items, not a single string of separated values.

Comment: This is not a web app, it's a MS Access app. And I'm looking for something like this, but with HIERARCHYID instead of self joins: https://cjaysql.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/product-category-hierarchy-with-breadcrumb-trail-using-cte-query/

Comment: `hierarchyid` doesn't help you for an infinite join, it can only help with questions like top ancestor or all children. You are still going to need a rCTE. Just use `GetAncestor(1)` to get the parent `hierarchyid` value, and make sure that column is indexed.

Comment: Thank you, Charlieface, I thought so. Could you by any chance try to elaborate on this and show me an example?

Comment: Something like this perhaps https://dbfiddle.uk/DYANrLKr ?

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you need a breadcrumb trail for a *given* category? Or *all* categories at once? Thinking about this from a frontend perspective I'd guess the former. And, if so, we can do this in a way that doesn't need a recursive CTE.

Comment: @BenThul Hi Ben, I need it for a given category. But the recursive CTE is needed anyway because it puts the Node trail together... Meaning: All products > then CTE runs > Category A > CTE runs agains > Subcategory. Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: That you only need to decompose one category and that you're already using hierarchyid means that you *don't* need to use a recursive CTE as you have all of the information necessary to find all ancestors for that category stored in the hierarchyid. Let me tidy up a solution and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need a recursive CTE, unless you pre-calculate the breadcrumb as your create or update the hierarchy.

You can get the parent ID using `.GetAncestor(1)` on the `Node` column.

Filter the CTE so the final result only returns rows which have recursed up to the top.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      BreadCrumb = CAST(t.CategoryName AS nvarchar(max)),
      ParentNode = t.Node.GetAncestor(1)
    FROM YourTable t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      cte.CategoryID,
      cte.Node,
      cte.CategoryName,
      CONCAT(t.CategoryName, ' -> ', cte.BreadCrumb),
      t.Node.GetAncestor(1)
    FROM cte
    JOIN YourTable t ON t.Node = cte.ParentNode
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.ParentNode IS NULL;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/DYANrLKr)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're already using hierarchyid, you have everything you need to work your way back from a given category all the way up the hierarchy. First, a table-valued function to break apart a given hierarchyid into all of its constituent parts:

```sql
create or alter function decomposeHierarchy(@h hierarchyid)
returns table
as
return
    select h = @h.GetAncestor(n-1)
    from dbo.Numbers as n
    where n.n <= @h.GetLevel()+1;
go
```

Where `dbo.Numbers` is just a tally table starting at 1. Note - the ±1 in the TVF definition is a consequence of my tally table starting at 1 while `GetLevel` is 0-based. Also note - you could probably get away with using [GENERATE_SERIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of a tally table if you so desire. I've also gone so far as to write a small CLR function to do this decomposition in the past.

Once we have a means by which to decompose the hierarchy, it's a simple matter joining the constituent hierarchyids back to the source data and concat-ing them together.

```sql
declare @t table (
    CategoryID int,
    [Node] hierarchyid,
    CategoryName varchar(100)
);

insert into @t 
    (CategoryID, [Node], CategoryName)
values 
    (1, 0x,'Products'),
    (2, 0x58,'Main Category 1'),
    (3, 0x68,'Main Category 2'),
    (4, 0x5AC0,'Subcategory 1A'),
    (5, 0x5B40,'Subcategory 1B');

declare @CategoryID int = 5;
declare @h hierarchyid = (
    select [Node]
    from @t
    where CategoryID = @CategoryID
);
select STRING_AGG(CategoryName, ' > ') within group (order by c.[Node].GetLevel())
from dbo.decomposeHierarchy(@h) as d
join @t as c
    on d.h = c.[Node];
```